# What is wavelet tranform in simple words?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, wavelets, fourier-transform

I have read wiki and other sources and have still problem understanding the wavelet transform.

What is the basic idea in simple words?

Does the Fourier uncertainty hold for wavelet transform?

Answer (score 1):

I like the analogy with traffic lights. With Fourier analysis you can tell the light has been an exact green frequency but you don't have information of the time it occurred. With wavelets you can tell the light was kind of green around a certain time. You sacrifice knowing the exact frequency and instead get approximations of the time and frequency.